# Fetch tags from database with 3 linked tables

Tags: php

I'm trying to get out all tags linked to a blog post, and are using 3 tables for storing of blog post, tags and tag_link_blog like this

```
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| BLOG POST TABLE  | TAGS        |  TAGS_LINK_BLOG |
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| ID               |  ID         |  ID             |
| TITLE            |  TAG        |  TAG_ID         |
| POST             |             |  BLOG_ID        |
| ++++             |             |                 |
+------------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

I've manged to write some code to get the tag name related to the blog post I'm requesting but it is by first running a db query to get the blog post and its ID (that have to be done either way), then use that ID to do do a new query and select the tag ID's related to that blog post ID, and then a last query to get the TAG names related to the tag ID.

I have never worked with tables that link together like this before but, I'm guessing it have to be a better way to do this. So underneath are the code I'm using now. Is this a ok way to do this or are there a way that is much better and faster?

```
$db_conn = new Database(); // connect to database
$stmt = $db_conn->connect->prepare("SELECT TAG_ID FROM `TAGS_LINK_BLOG` WHERE BLOG_ID = $id"); // prepare statement
$stmt->execute(); // select from database
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // Get the result

$tag_id = [];

// Push tag id to array
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($tag_id, $row['TAG_ID']);
}

$db_conn->free_close($result, $stmt); // free result and close db connection

// Get tag name by the tag id
foreach($tag_id as $tags) {

    $db_conn = new Database(); // connect to database
    $stmt = $db_conn->connect->prepare("SELECT TAG FROM `TAGS` WHERE ID = $tags"); // prepare statement
    $stmt->execute(); // select from database
    $result = $stmt->get_result(); // Get the result

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo $row['TAG'];

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have on occasion used a [group_concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) after joining multiple tables to group in your case multiple tags to a single result. SQL would be as so.

```
SELECT b.id, GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag SEPARATOR ' ') as tags
FROM blog_post_table b
LEFT JOIN tags_link_blog tlb ON tlb.blog_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = tbl.tag_id
GROUP BY b.id
```

then after the result is returned you will just require a single loop to loop through the result set. You will also need to `explode(" ",$row[$tag])` the return array to make this into it's own array as group concat return a string.

Comment: I will try that :)